# command not found: grails, but path & installation is correct

Tags: grails

I had grails installed and running correctly several days ago, but I came back from a vacation and am now getting the message command not found: grails. I searched, and all the results dealt with $PATH and $GRAILS_HOME, which are set up correctly, as far as I can tell. I set them up when I installed grails and had it working, I have made no changes to them.

here is my how I have my environment variables configured in my dotfiles:

```
export GRAILS_HOME="~/grails"
export PATH="$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Note: I installed version 2.5.1 using [these instructions](https://grails.org/wiki/installation)

UPDATE: I tried running the grails script inside the bin folder, and it ran correctly. However, I still cannot get the command grails to run from the command line.

Comment: Make your life easier. Install Chocolatey and then install grails. It will just do this for you.

Comment: It's for work, and we generally prefer to keep our installation methods consistent as we've run into debugging issues otherwise. I'll ask about Chocolatey, but I'd prefer to understand the problem

Comment: http://sdkman.io is the de facto standard for that sort of thing in the Groovy and Grails community.  It looks like Chocolatey is a Windows focused thing.  @AlecWilson is using OS X as far as I can tell from his path.

Comment: The docs at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/guide/gettingStarted.html are a better resource than the wiki page linked in the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, but they have exactly the same installation instructions that I used.

Answer (score 1):

Pointing GRAILS_HOME to `~/.grails` won't work.  You need to point GRAILS_HOME to wherever you have Grails installed.  `~/.grails/` is where Grails stores a number of things, not where the installation is.

Comment: That was actually a typo on my part, sorry about that. I have $GRAILS_HOME set to ~/grails, which is what the installation instructions I used recommended.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably resolved by now however for whoever is looking this problem up, maybe needless to say but make sure you don't spell any capital letters, such as Grails (misspelled) as it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but one that I am almost embarrassed to resort to. I realized that simply running the grails script from grails/bin worked, so I aliased grails as:

```
alias grails="~/grails/bin/grails"
```

I assume this is a pretty suboptimal solution, but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is the `~` character that is not being interpreted as your home directory. Just use `$HOME` instead:

```sh
export GRAILS_HOME="$HOME/grails"
export PATH="$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"
```